# Golang CORS doesn't accept the given ip, nor '*' [SOLVED]

Tags: go, server, cors, digital-ocean, private-network-access

I'm using a Golang backend, which can be found in this repository: https://github.com/BuddhiLW/free-riding

I'm using the given command, using the `fasthttp` package,

```golang
ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

I also tried replacing `"*"` with `"161.35.yy.xxx:*"` which is the ip for my droplet.

When I run locally, using exactly the same setup, it works:

```
sudo docker run -dit --name my-running-frontend -p 8080:80 clojurescript-frontend
sudo docker run -it --rm --name my-running-backend -p 8181:8181 golang-backend
```

But, remotely, when I go to `161.35.yy.xxx:80`, and use the service, I get CORS error.

The error, in the console:

```
main.js:3779     GET http://localhost:8181/free-riding/duckduckgo.com net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8181/free-riding/duckduckgo.com' from origin 'http://161.35.96.204:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

In the `Network` tab:

```
Request URL:
http://localhost:8181/free-riding/duckduckgo.com
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Comment: What CORS error are you getting? Edit your question and add the error message. Also, add the relevant client code.

Comment: Done, edited @jub0bs I didn't post any client code, because I don't believe it to be relevant. At least, I don't see anything wrong with it. You can inspect the code, the application running etc, in the github page I posted above.

Comment: See https://github.com/WICG/private-network-access

Comment: [jub0bs/fcors](https://github.com) allows you to configure your server for CORS and Private Network Access. See https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jub0bs/fcors/risky#PrivateNetworkAccess

Comment: Yeah, I managed with the help of these resources.